# Slow Query: Data categorization

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table (AllProducts) which contains product information. It has 16 columns and approximately 125000 rows.

I need to create a unique value in the database, as there is no unique value present in the table. I can not use the auto increment feature as my database gets emptied out and filled again on a daily basis (and thus id's for specific products will change).

I want to use a varchar field (url) to be a unique value. In order to do this I created a view (AllProductsCategories) which makes sure the combination of url and shop is unique.

```
select min(`a`.`insertionTime`) AS `insertionTime`,
`a`.`shop` AS `shop`,
min(`a`.`name`) AS `name`,
min(`a`.`category`) AS `category`,
max(`a`.`description`) AS `description`,
min(`a`.`price`) AS `price`,
`a`.`url` AS `url`,
avg(`a`.`image`) AS `image`,
min(`a`.`fromPrice`) AS `fromPrice`,
min(`a`.`deliveryCosts`) AS `deliveryCosts`,
max(`a`.`stock`) AS `stock`,
max(`a`.`deliveryTime`) AS `deliveryTime`,
max(`a`.`ean`) AS `ean`,
max(`a`.`color`) AS `color`,
max(`a`.`size`) AS `size`,max(`a`.`brand`) AS `brand` 
from `AllProducts` `a` group by `a`.`url`,`a`.`shop` 
order by NULL
```

This works fine but is quite slow. The query below takes 51 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT * FROM ProductsCategories ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 50
```

I am quite new to MySQL and experimented by indexing the following columns: category, name, url, shop and shop/url.

Now my questions:
1) Is this the correct approach if I want to ensure that the url field is unique? I currently use a group by to merge all info about one url. An alternative approach could be to delete duplicates (not sure how to do this though).
2) If the current approach is OK, how can I speed up this process?

Comment: You should use constraints so you don't get the problem in the first place..

Comment: I'm probably not understanding all of this. But *if* you rebuild you DB, generating *new* unique ID daily, won't that break all the bookmarks of your users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is re-loaded every day, then you should just fix it when it is reloaded.

Perhaps that is not possible.  I would suggest the following approach, assuming that the triple `url`, `shop`, `InsertionTime` is unique.  First, build an index on `url, shop, InsertionTime`.  Then use this query:

```
select ap.*
from AllProducts ap
where ap.InsertionTime = (select InsertionTime
                          from AllProducts ap2
                          where ap2.url = ap.url and
                                ap2.shop = ap.shop
                          order by InsertionTime
                          limit 1
                         );
```

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `from` clause of a view.  It does allow them in the `select` and `where` (and `having`) clauses.  This should cycle through the table, doing an index lookup for each row, just returning the ones that have the minimum insertion time.

Comment: Great suggestion; works like a charm. Only had to change 'from AllProducts ap' to 'from AllProducts ap2' in the subquery.